# How to create a disc image of my existing Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, cd-image

I have fresh install Ubuntu 14.04 with all the coding stack that I need. I would like to create and image of this installation for duplicate it in the other computers without the same effort. Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: What kind of disc image? Full raw copy, which backs up absolutely everything there is? Or file copy? (in the second case you might wait)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fsarchiver](http://www.fsarchiver.org/), [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org), dd or [ddrescue](http://www2.opensourceforensics.org/node/49), [partimage](http://partimage.org), [remastersys](http://remastersys.sourceforge.net/), [G4L](http://sourceforge.net/projects/g4l/) (Ghost for Linux), ...

Please do some research into these tools and if you get stuck, open a new question.

If you just want to install the same packages on other machines:

#### Step 1: Store the list of installed packages

Run the following command on the source machine to store the installed packages names in ~/pkglist:

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | sed "s/.*deinstall//" | sed "s/install$//g" > ~/pkglist
```

#### Step 2: Transfer your config

Use `scp` or `rsync` or even a flash drive to transfer your home directory (`~/*`, `~/.*`), the source list (`/etc/apt/sources.list`) and any other files you customized or installed (like apache config under `/etc` or software on `/opt`) from the source machine to the target one.

#### Step 3: Install packages

On the target machine run the following command in a failsafe terminal session to install your packages:

```
sudo aptitude update && cat pkglist | xargs sudo aptitude install -y
```

[Source](http://eggsonbread.com/2010/01/28/move-ubuntu-to-another-computer-in-3-simple-steps/)